# What is the correct way to write down these numerals with words

Tags: склонение, числительные

Consider the sentence:

> "В 1955-1991 годы Польша являлась участником Варшавского договора."

What is the correct grammatical form of the numerals?

Is it

> "В тысяча девятьсот пятьдесят пятый - тысяча девятьсот девяносто первый годы Польша являлась участником Варшавского договора."

or something else?

Comment: Just as a side note, incorrect declension of numerals is one of the most frequent mistakes done by native Russian speakers.

Comment: because they're so unwieldy, in fluent speech one has to almost pause to inflect a compound numeral correctly, which hinders the speech and so is often disregarded in favor of fluency most likely subconsciously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> С (одна) тысяча девятьсот пятьдесят пятого по (одна) тысяча девятьсот
>   девяносто первый год Польша была участником Варшавского договора.

PS. "*В 1955-1991 годы*" is ungrammatical. But since it's not really clear what the correct form of "год" in this case would be, usually "*в 1955-1991 **гг**.*" is used.

In such cases *"гг."* stands for plural of "*год*" in a suitable declination (*годах, годы, etc*).